# Cannot create directory permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, capistrano

I am deploying my rails application to a vps. On `cap deploy:setup` I get the error that mkdir: cannot create directory `/apps'.

I am using `set :user_sudo, false` in my deploy.rb file.

I am a linux newbie, How can I give permission to the current user to create directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have (or should not) hand permission to create directories to the root ('/') directory.

Change the `mkdir` command to create the directory in a directory where the process has the appropriate permissions.